# ¿Por qué no me aparecen todas las opciones para reportar una pregunta?

Tags: soporte, cierre-de-preguntas, motivos-de-cierre, reportes

Quería reportar una pregunta que la veo muy amplia, pues no describe el problema que tiene y pide una solución a algo muy complejo.

Para mí, cae en la categoría **No está claro lo que se pregunta** pero resulta que solo encuentro estas opciones:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Es este el primer menú que te aparece al apretar en "reportar"? ¿Podrías indicar si la pregunta es antigua? ¿Ya la reportaste antes?

Comment: Si, es ene el menu reportar que esta junto a la opcion de editar, al parecer ese menu se despliega cuando ya la pregunta esta en modo "puesto en espera"

Comment: Ah, ¿o sea que la pregunta ya estaba cerrada?

Comment: Estaba puesta en espera

Answer (score 4):

Como indicas en los comentarios, la pregunta ya está cerrada. Bueno, técnicamente "en espera", que es un estado transitorio que se da a las recién cerradas para animar al autor a mejorarla. Por tanto, la pelota está en el tejado del AP (autor de la pregunta) y se espera que la mejora.

Dado pues el caso de que está cerrada, ¿para qué quieres reportar que quieres que se cierre? Es redundante porque ya lo está, de ahí que no te aparezca la opción de hacerlo y solamente opciones más "duras" reservados para casos más complejos (spam, etc).

Resumiendo: no toques na, que lo que quieres hacer ya se ha hecho :)

Comment: Ahota entiendo... Lo que sucede es que la opcion de reportar siempre aparece y al desplegar el menu no da una indicación o aclaración del Estado de la pregunta

Comment: Pero es que el estado de la pregunta ya se ve en el banner de debajo, ¿no? O incluso en el título, que pone "en espera"

Answer (score 1):

Parece que estas confundiendo las opciones de "cierre" y "reportar".

En tu caso tú quieres votar para cerrar la pregunta porque es *muy amplia*(aunque tambien señalas que es poco clara que es otro motivo de cierre)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero estas usando la opción de reportar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el primer caso el objetivo es principalmente que el usuario pueda mejorar su pregunta para que encaje con los requisitos que se exige en SO. En cambio el segundo es señalar que la pregunta/respuesta es insalvable.

Comment: No creo que sea el caso. Este usuario no tiene privilegios para cerrar (está en 3000), pero en su menú de reporte debería aparecer la opción de cerrar.

Comment: @fedorqui quizas... hace tiempo que obtuve esos privilegios y no recuerdo como era el comportamiento de las opciones. Quizas tenga razon :-)

Comment: @fedorqui parece que tienes razon, comprobe que en otra comunidad que no tengo ese privilegio la opción de cerrar esta en la opción de reportar

Comment: Yo también tuve que mirarlo :) En https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges veo que votar para cerrar está en 3000 y el AP tiene algo menos.